# What's an easy way to detect a file has changed and update it automatically?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, build-process

What's an easy way to detect a file has changed and update it automatically?

For example if I have a js/css file that I just uploaded, I'd like the server to detect I uploaded new js/css files and minify them automatically right then and there.

EDIT: I've tried minifying at run time and found out it's not efficient. It's interesting to note, that the file was minified for anyone requesting the file which was an overhead in itself and it was actually faster to not minify the file for delivery.

Ideally, the file should be minified within a few seconds of upload. Instead of a constantly polling system, is there an event based system out there that I could look into?

EDIT: I used mikhailov answer and added the following to the incron file:

```
/var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
```

Comment: Just give me some names so I can start. I know nothing about this. I don't even know what to google.

Comment: you could keep a table containing each file you want included, and their last modified date. then have a cron job running daily that checks your files against the recorded dates, if any are newer, then run the minify process and update the table with the new dates.  It wouldn't be immediate, but it would be "automated"

Comment: It needs to be immediate though. At least within a few seconds of upload. Is using a cron job the way to go?

Comment: you could schedule a cron job to run as frequently as once a minute

Comment: You might want to check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030028/auto-minify-javascript-css-files-after-update

Comment: @Maverick976: Thanks for the link. I understand the minifying process itself pretty well but I'd like to automate the process.

Comment: great info in that link.  I'm using git so the post-commit hooks will work great for me, thanks!

Comment: Isn't that at run time though? I already had setup something which minified at run time and found out it's not efficient.

Comment: no, the post-commit hooks would be run right after the version control system deploys the code to the server, after you commit a change to your js file.  There are probably many ways of setting it up.

Comment: @RightClick: Do you mean the link that Maverick posted?

Comment: **inotify** is what you need

Comment: @mikhailov: Oooh, that looks pretty good. I'd like to see what other suggestions people come up with though.

Comment: What are you using to upload the file? Maybe your file uploader has a plugin which will minify JS and CSS upon uploading.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I'm just uploading via sftp. As far as I can tell it doesn't have that functionality and doesn't support any plugins but I'm open to trying something that does.

Comment: You are doing command-line sftp uploads?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: No, I'm using a client.

Comment: sftp is a protocol, what client are you using?

Comment: Thanks, not sure if this post will help but I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359473/automagically-minify-css-and-javascript-on-upload

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Yeah, that's interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried inotify and incrond yet?

Comment: @mikhailov: I'll be trying it out this week. I took a break on the weekend. When you say inotify you mean this correct? http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php What's incrond? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @rotaercz I'd recommend to take a look [this blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) about inotify, it shows the similar use case that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inotify is a recommended pattern to get notified re file system events (file created, modified or deleted), what [Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify):

> Inotify (inode notify) is a Linux kernel subsystem that acts to extend
>   filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those
>   changes to applications.

See the similar [use case](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/): how to get notified of files being copied over rsync.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting close but can you provide some more details on how to use it? I logged on to my server with putty and I installed it using, 'sudo apt-get install incron'. But now I'm not sure how things work?

Comment: @rotaercz to edit the incron file type *incrontab -e* and put the following content */tmp IN_ALL_EVENTS logger "/tmp action for $# file"*. Then you can see logger make an action based on new file created of deleted. The log is available from here: /var/log/messages

Comment: How do you stop incron? I currently went into a loop because I made it so when the js file is modified, minify it, however the minifying itself is modifying the file so it goes on forever.

Comment: This link was really helpful in figuring things out. http://www.pablumfication.co.uk/2010/09/23/incron-file-system-event-monitoring/